# Wordpress click counter

Tags: php, wordpress, click, counter

There's a website that includes downloading files. I need to attach click counter to links with following statistic display on separate page like "file title - n downloadings"

File titles and links for downloading are generate via standart, barely changed `wp-playlist(/wp-includes/media.php)` as follows:

Title:

```
<span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-title">
  <?php
      /* translators: playlist item title */
      printf( _x( '&#8220;%s&#8221;', 'playlist item title' ), '{{ data.title }}' );
  ?>
</span>
```

Link:

```
<a title="download" href="{{ data.src }}" download="">download</a>
```